# Wave function - expectation value of position time independence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Suppose we are given the one-dimensional Wave Function:

$$Ψ(x,t=0)=c_1ψ_1(x)+c_2ψ_3(x)+c_3ψ_5(x)$$ with orthogonal eigenfunctions $ψ_n.$ How can I prove that the expectation value of position $\langle x \rangle$ does not depend on time?

I start with the definition: $$\langle x \rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Ψ^*(x,t)xΨ(x,t) dx$$

Afterwards, I assume the expression: $$Ψ(x,t)=\sum_{n}ψ_n(x)e^{-\frac{iE_nt}{\hbar}}$$ could be useful if placed in the integral, but how exactly?

Comment: An "eigenfunction" is an attribute of an operator. Of what operator are these eigenfunctions?

Comment: You can't prove it, because it's not true. Things can _move_ in QM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be true if your time-independent solutions $\psi_n(x)$ have definite parity given by $(-1)^n$, i.e $\psi_n(-x)=(-1)^n\psi_n(x)$.  Then, your integral for $\langle x\rangle$ will contain terms of the type
$$
\psi_m(x) \left(x\psi_n(x)\right).
$$
Since all the terms in your sum have the same (odd) parity, $x\psi_n(x)$ will have even parity, and so produce an integrand of the type $\psi_m(x)\left(x\psi_n(x)\right)$, which will be odd.
The integral (when it converges) of an odd function evaluated between symmetric limits is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it? It just depends.

If each $\psi_n$ has a **different** eigenvalue, then the system will evolve in time; probabilities will vary.

However, if all $\psi_n$ have the same eigenvalue (anyhow), then the system is stationary.

*All this being as long as we're talking about eigenfunctions **of the Hamiltonian operator**.*

The reason is simple, if all those functions have the same energy, then you can write

$$\Psi=e^{i\frac{E_n}{\hbar}t}\cdot \sum_k c_k\  \psi_k(\vec{x})$$

And the first factor is a global constant phase factor, which doesn't affect probabilities, since its squared modulus is 1.

However, if each $\psi_n$ has its own energy, then you cannot do this, and each $\psi_n$'s contribution will change in time differently, which will affect $|\Psi|^2$ and hence the probabilities.